# Server Info Command Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
    @client.command()
    async def server(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.guild.name} Info", description = "Information of this Server", color = discord.Colour.blue())
    embed.add_field(name = 'Server ID', value = f"{ctx.guild.id}", inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = 'Created On', value = ctx.guild.created_at.strftime("%b %d %Y"), inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = 'Owner', value = f"{ctx.guild.owner}", inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = 'Members', value = f'{ctx.guild.member_count} Members', inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = 'Channels', value = f'{ctx.guild.text_channel_count} Text | {ctx.guild.voice_channel_count} Voice', inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = 'Region', value = f'{ctx.guild.region}', inline = True)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url = ctx.guild.icon_url)
    embed.set_footer(text = "⭐ • Duo")    
    embed.set_author(name = f'{ctx.guild.name}', url = embed.Empty, icon_url = {ctx.guild.icon_url})
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

**I wrote this Code, everything seems fine, when I run the bot, there are no errors. The terminal is blank, but when I run this command, it doesn't work, it doesn't send a response, there is no error in the terminal also. Please Help..**

Comment: Use `print` statements to see where the bot gets stuck. I also never heard of `embed.Empty`, what is this?

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, you're not indenting properly. I also have never heard of `url = embed.Empty`.

As an aside, I replaced the `embed.set_author` line `embed.set_author(name = f'{ctx.guild.name}', icon_url = {ctx.guild.icon_url})` with `embed.set_author(name = f'{ctx.author.name}' icon_url = {ctx.message.author.avatar_url}` because it seemed to me like that was the line you wanted to display information about the author rather than the guild.

```py
@client.command()
async def server(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.guild.name} Info", description = "Information of this Server", color = discord.Colour.blue())
    embed.add_field(name = 'Server ID', value = f"{ctx.guild.id}", inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = 'Created On', value = ctx.guild.created_at.strftime("%b %d %Y"), inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = 'Owner', value = f"{ctx.guild.owner}", inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = 'Members', value = f'{ctx.guild.member_count} Members', inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = 'Channels', value = f'{ctx.guild.text_channel_count} Text | {ctx.guild.voice_channel_count} Voice', inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = 'Region', value = f'{ctx.guild.region}', inline = True)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url = ctx.guild.icon_url)
    embed.set_footer(text = "⭐ • Duo")    
    embed.set_author(name = f'{ctx.author.name}' icon_url = {ctx.message.author.avatar_url}
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

If resolving your indentation and removing `url = embed.Empty` doesn't do the trick, then you'll have to run debug print statements line by line until you isolate the troublesome line.

Answer (score 1):

There are few things wrong here.

### 1. Indentation.

This is basic stuff. Indent every line after the `async def server(ctx):` line.

### 2. Read the documentation!

If you look at the documentation for [guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#guild), you can see that `guild.text_channel_count` and `guild.voice_channel_count` don't exist. Instead, you have to do `len(guild.text_channels)` and `len(guild.voice_channels)` instead.

### 3. Unnecessary braces

On the second last line, I'm not sure why you have the `{}` wrapped around `icon_url = {ctx.message.author.avatar_url}`. So get rid of those.

Also, the `url=embed.Empty` is completely unnecessary as well as it is the default value for `embed.set_author()` ([see here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Embed.set_author)). So get rid of that.

### 4. [Not a mistake, but quick tip]

`ctx.guild.owner` by itself will give a `Member` object, however as you put it in a f-string it will give an ugly representation (something like `<discord.member_object_at_12391873123> or something idk` so instead do `ctx.guild.owner.mention` so it would actually show the owner of the server in mention format (however since its in an embed it won't actually ping them)

In all, you should have:

```py
@client.command()
async def server(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.guild.name} Info", description="Information of this Server", color=discord.Colour.blue())
    embed.add_field(name='Server ID', value=f"{ctx.guild.id}", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name='Created On', value=ctx.guild.created_at.strftime("%b %d %Y"), inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name='Owner', value=f"{ctx.guild.owner.mention}", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name='Members', value=f'{ctx.guild.member_count} Members', inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name='Channels', value=f'{len(ctx.guild.text_channels)} Text | {len(ctx.guild.voice_channels)} Voice', inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name='Region', value=f'{ctx.guild.region}', inline=True)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.guild.icon_url) 
    embed.set_footer(text="⭐ • Duo")    
    embed.set_author(name=f'{ctx.author.name}' icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Edit: I forgot to mention that I have formatted your code a bit to adhere to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (as in no spaces around the `=` in function calls, etc.)